# What would be the 19-F decoupled proton NMR of this complex [PtH(PF3)4]-?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

The proton is in the equatorial position and the geometry of the complex [PtH(PF3)4]- is trigonal bipyramidal.  The NMR is 19-F-decoupled proton NMR.

My thoughts were that the proton would couple to the platinum centre, but then I wasn't sure about the phosphorous chemical environments.

Are the two axial PF3 groups in a different chemical environment to the two equatorial PF3 groups?

If so would you end up with 6 sets of triplets? Is that a doublet of triplet of triplets?

Comment: Pt-195 (spin-1/2) only has 34% natural abundance, so you need to consider that the spectrum will be an overlay of two sub-spectra: one without Pt-195 and one with. You've identified the sub-spectrum with Pt-195 as being a dtt correctly (you can afford to be more confident - your logic is correct!). However, that's only 34% of the total spectrum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  So the second sub-spectra would be a triplet of triplets? @orthocresol

Comment: Yup, that's right. Lastly, you would want to consider how to arrange the two subspectra together.

Comment: You might also want to consider that the 195Pt satellites are broadened significantly due to CSA relaxation. At higher fields (certainly above 400MHz), the 195Pt satellites appear as broad lumps only - you probably only see the H-P couplings in the 195Pt satellites at lower fields.